# How to show two dates in one calculated column

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, date-time

I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2010. I have two columns, start date and ending date. I want to make calculated column which shows both of them in the same column. Everything is okay till I add both dates, start and ending dates to the column.

`=[StartDate]&" "&[EndingDate]`

This code returns the dates in wrong format. It returns them in something like this 41523 but I would like it to return them in dd/mm/yyyy.

But if I put just [StartDate] or [EndingDate] all alone to the calculated column, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
=(YEAR(StartDate)&"/"&MONTH(StartDate)&"/"&DAY(StartDate))&" "&(YEAR(EndDate)&"/"&MONTH(EndDate)&"/"&DAY(EndDate))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the column how to display the information.  "MM/dd/yyyy"  This is what I put on mine:
="Created on: "&TEXT(Created,"MM/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers work. Did anyone bother to test them?

After looking elsewhere and working it out myself, here's what works:

```
=TEXT([Start Date],"mm/dd/yy")&" - "&TEXT([End Date],"mm/dd/yy")
```

You can adjust the way the date shows by using the mm/dd/yy part, which is intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE([StartDate],"-", [EndingDate])
```

for  [more reference click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx)

Comment: Concatenate function still shows the days wrong... StartDate 11.11.2013 is shown 41589 and EndingDate 29.11.2013 is shown in 41607.